# What is practical size for bcache cache size with respect to hdd size?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, cache, bcache

There are plenty of manuals how to implement bcache, how to select correct bucket size, how to resize (grow) backing device and so on. This includes, but doesn't limits to [in-kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/bcache.txt), [bcache website](https://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/), the [ArchLinux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bcache) and so on.

However, nowhere I was able to find any information how cache device size affects overall storage performance. Not only documentation, but also there is hard to find a useful benchmark.

It is often thought "the more cache, the better", but this approach also has its limit. More cache is more expensive, and in the end it renders whole idea of using cache useless. Why using cache if my SSD is itself large enough? If assigned cache space wouldn't be used, why ever adding that much space, when it clearly will be better to split an SSD and only use part of it as a cache, and using another part directly?

So, are there any practical recommendations on how many cache a certain backing device could require? For example, if we have 500 GB HDD in the laptop, how much SSD space is needed to cache it efficiently?

Comment: Usually questions about cache sizing play into what you actually do with a given system. For example the storage hierachie, medium as well as the actual usage pattern.

Comment: Of course I understand the usage pattern is playing a role. I think the whole this role could be reduced to some effective volume of a "hot" data on the backing medium. It will consist of actual user data which gets accessed frequently, file system metadata and metadata on other hierarchy layers. Let's assume I have a way to calculate this "hot" data size and I/O pattern (how much is often read and rarely updated how much is often updated and rarely read and so on). Then, based on this, how to calculate concrete required cache size?

Comment: If you do have that information you already finished your calculation. Assuming you don't have any unexpected overhead due to the way bcache works. Keep in mind that bcache in its nature isn't applied to every operation.

Comment: In part I'm asking about exactly this, i.e. which overhead should I expect.

Comment: Have a look at what a btree is and how it works. Have a look at the statistics provided by the driver. Those should be able to give you an idea of what you're asking for. You won't find "there is 20% overhead" statement as again it is influenced by various factors that you need to determine based on your workload. Define a workload, set it up and test how it behaves. That's probably an approach that will give you the quickest idea about what you're doing. With your 500 GB laptop HDD example buying a 500 GB laptop SSD would probably be easier.